# Duplicated tests in Test Explorer Specflow + VS2017

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I updated VS 2015 to VS 2017 and I have latest versions for Specflow and nUnit. 
At VS2015 all worked fine, now at VS2017 test explorer I see duplicated tests and folders where feature files is. 
[Duplicated specflow tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEVHj.jpg)
I was forced disabled all extensions for test explorer, it fixed issue when you can't go to feature file from tests explorer.

Comment: **Tools -> Extensions and Updates ->Microsoft Visual Studio Test Platform** should be enabled. It'll fix duplicates, but still can't find how to turn off nesting.

Answer (score 2):

You ***may*** have multiple test adapters referenced in your project.

For example, if I have both of the following nuget packages in my project, my tests are duplicated:

- NUnit3TestAdapter
- Specrun.Runner

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to change the feature file property 'Copy to Output Directory' from possibly 'Copy if Newer' or 'Copy Always' to 'Do not Copy'. This will ensure that your feature file present in the project directory is not copied to bin\Debug. In such an event, Visual Studio Test Explorer detects two feature files and hence the duplication.

[Change value of parameter, Copy to Output Directory to "Do not copy"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX8rS.png)